# Preview or View Site As Any User

Tags: impersonation, support

Is it possible to preview a whole Sharepoint 2010 site as a specific user? I am thinking from a support perspective where a user phones up and asks "why cant I see x" or "where do i go to find y".

It would be great for a support person to be able to go into the site as that user with the same set of permissions. Is this possible? Any other solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asside from logging on as them (which I do not recommend) you could create a test user and assign it the same permissions.  I should mention that there are many good free screen sharing tools available now.  One of them is [SharedView](http://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=94) by Microsoft.  These will allow you to see the user's exact desktop as you talk with them.

Comment: SharedView etc are not possible in this environment

Comment: Then I think having a test user that you can apply/remove permissions to is the best way to go.  It would be best to not use your own.  There are some third party tools out there that will allow you to copy all of a user's permissions to another user's account.  That would make it easy for you if you can find one.  It seems like Idera makes such a product.

Comment: @RobWilson - can you link me to any of these tools, my googling has turned up little. Thanks for you help btw +1. I am not a SP person, just trying to help out a client.

Comment: oh I cant +1 as I dont have 15 - can I borrow some of my SO rep;)

Comment: Idera:
http://www.idera.com/Products/SharePoint/SharePoint-security-manager/

Lightning Tools: 
http://www.lightningtools.com/deliverpoint/sharepoint-permission-management.aspx

I tried to find a PowerShell script to do this, but couldn't find one.  If I ever find one or find time to write one, I'll update the comments here.

BTW: Marking a response as an answer is as good as a +1. It should let you do that since it is your question.  I voted your question up so that should help. ;)  It is a great question.